# Outlook API Refresh Token

Tags: node.js, outlook, oauth-2.0

I'm using the simple-oauth2 library to get the token, but it only has the acess token and the id token.

How do I get the refresh token?

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem.
you need to add scope parameter `['offline_access']`
in `authUrl` add:

```
 {access_type:'offline', approval_prompt: 'force'}
```

This should give you refresh token along `auth_tokens` and `id_token`

Comment: Adding `'offline_access'` in the scope  worked for me :)

Comment: @RajithaWarusavitarana the same worked for me as well

Answer (score 0):

The Refresh tokens are issued by the authorization server and it is up to the authorization server's discretion to issue them. Since you mentioned Outlook API you could you Microsoft Graph API for refresh token.

Please look at these links: [Outlook Dev Center](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/getstarted), [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization) for details on how to get a refresh token for Outlook API.

Comment: So, in order to use Microsoft Graph API I need a tenant id, which I get with a subscription to Azure? Is there no other way?

Answer (score 0):

```
function refresh_token($token)
{
  // Build the form data to post to the OAuth2 token endpoint
  $token_request_data = array(
    "grant_type" => 'refresh_token',
    "refresh_token" => $token,
    "redirect_uri" => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token',
    "resource" => "https://outlook.office365.com/",
    "client_id" => self::$clientId,
    "client_secret" => self::$clientSecret
  );

  // Calling http_build_query is important to get the data
  // formatted as Azure expects.
  $token_request_body = http_build_query($token_request_data);
  error_log("Request body: ".$token_request_body);

  $curl = curl_init(self::$authority.self::$tokenUrl);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $token_request_body);
  /*custom*/
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  /*custom end*/
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  error_log("curl_exec done.");

  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  error_log("Request returned status ".$httpCode);
  if ($httpCode >= 400) {
    return array('errorNumber' => $httpCode,
                 'error' => 'Token request returned HTTP error '.$httpCode);
  }

  // Check error
  $curl_errno = curl_errno($curl);
  $curl_err = curl_error($curl);
  if ($curl_errno) {
    $msg = $curl_errno.": ".$curl_err;
    error_log("CURL returned an error: ".$msg);
    return array('errorNumber' => $curl_errno,
                 'error' => $msg);
  }

  curl_close($curl);

  // The response is a JSON payload, so decode it into
  // an array.
  $json_vals = json_decode($response, true);
  error_log("TOKEN RESPONSE:");
  foreach ($json_vals as $key=>$value) {
    error_log("  ".$key.": ".$value);
  }

  return $json_vals;
}
```